# Loschmidt's paradox in Bohmian Mechanics

Tags: statistical-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, born-rule, bohmian-mechanics

In Bohmian mechanics, the position of the particles must have a random distribution given by $\rho = |\Psi|^2$, where $\Psi$ is the wave function, in order to be compatible with Born rule in standard Quantum Mechanics. If I understand correctly, this is referred to as the *quantum equilibrium hypothesis* (QEH). There is a priori no reason not to consider [non-quantum distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_non-equilibrium) but then an equivalent of Boltzmann H-theorem is claimed to guarantee that such a non-quantum distribution would very quickly relax to $\rho = |\Psi|^2$, and would therefore never be observed.

But then how would one evade Loschmidt's argument in this context? The equations of motions for the particles, and for the wave function, are definitively deterministic. The situation seems actually worse than in classical Newtonian mechanics since the particle do actually not have a real dynamic: the equations of motion boils down to the speed of the particle being directly determined by the wave function.

Comment: I'm not sure that Loschmidt's paradox has been resolved in any context? So it seems like you are asking one of the unsolved questions of physics. (first one on this list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_physics )

Comment: @JMLCarter: I would tend to disagree with that. Loschmidt's paradox was already very convincingly answered by Boltzmann. Note that this paradox is really about the apparent incompatibility between reversible microscopic equations of motion and irreversible macroscopic behavior, and I would contend that this aspect is rather well understood. The general problem of the arrow of time is of course more complex.

Comment: @JMLCarter: two nice references (among many others) that address this point of view on the irreversibility "paradox" are [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.0724) by Joel Lebowitz and [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/chao-dyn/9603009) by Jean Bricmont.

Comment: Actually, a discussion of the question raised by the OP can be found in the papers contained in [this book](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540420569). (It is not difficult to find copies of the book on the internet if you cannot access it directly.)

Comment: @Velenik. Thanks for the links. I don't want to hijack this thread with need for clarification special to me. I don't understand the distinction between this paradox and the problem of the arrow of time  (yet).

Comment: @JMLCarter: It's probably better not to sidetrack too much, so let me just say this. For me, the paradox is about the conceptual difficulty of reconciling microscopic reversibility with macroscopic irreversibility. The arrow of time involves additional subtleties, such as explaining why the universe "started" in a state with extremely low entropy. So the former is basically a mathematical question (relating to properties of the microscopic laws of motion when applied to macroscopic systems), while the latter is about properties of the universe. I don't know if I am very clear...